# How to disable an hooking to my process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi

Is there any debug/prepossessing param or any option under Windows 7 and visual studio to prevent from other processes hooking to my process?

I am writing a game for Windows, under Visual Studio, and was wondering if there is a way to disable user to hook to the game's process?

Comment: There are many forms of hook. What are you trying to prevent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, that's not possible.** Even if you *could* somehow disable hooking, the user could still attach a debugger to your process and do *anything they wanted*. That's by design, of course: it's how *you* debug the problem when you write it.

Once a user has installed a program on their machine, assuming they have sufficient privileges, they have *full control* over that program. Trying to limit it programmatically is a fool's errand.

The solution to this program is not to be found with code. You need to investigate the built-in Windows security model, like creating limited user accounts; ask more questions about that on Server Fault.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no.

On a Windows machine (like most other machines) a user with sufficient privileges will *always* have the ability to inspect and or modify the contents of your game process's address space.

That said, what sort of user(s) and or attack(s) are you looking to defend against?  What assets are you looking to protect?  Once you've identified these, you can start thinking about how to design your application such that attackers would have a more difficult time getting at what they want.

I'd start with reading up on [Threat Modeling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648644.aspx).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling is not possible. What you want to do is detecting byte patches, hooks or even just reading in the games memory region. But you better give up, because its not worth the time.